# Django: Different form field widget per form in formset

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to find best approach for what i want. And i could use some help for that.

I have Model A and Model B. Model B has

```
modela = forms.ForeignKey(Model a)
```

I want to create a view where you can edit both single Model A and several Model B's on same page. Django has formsets for this and they work great.

I have one detail though, that messes things up tiny bit. Namely - i want the widgets or model B fields to be different based on what choices they have done in previous fields of same object. Because - based on type, the widget has to be datetime picker input or plain textinput.

Model B looks like this:

```
class ModelB(models.Model):
    m0odela = models.ForeignKey(ModelA)
    target_value = models.CharField()
    target_type = models.CharField( choices = ( there are choices))
    target_threshold = models.CharField()
```

I know i can provide my own form for formset and i could do this widget assignment in that form.

But the problem is, that when formset has no instances/queryset then i cant check if 'target_type' has been set for forms instance. So i would have to do it based on self.data or self.initial in form. But self.initial is also not present in `form.__init__()`. What i can work with is self.data - but that is raw request.POST or request.GET data - which contains all keys like 'mymodelb_set-0-target_type'.

So i'm bit lost here. Do i have to do some key parsing and figure out which -target_type belongs to current form and get chosen value there and assign widgets based on this value? 
Or do i have to create my own subclass of BaseInlineFormSet and override _construc_form there somehow? So that form would have initial key with related data in **kwargs.

Has someone ran into this kind of problem before?

Alan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i had to solve it so i solved it as good/bad i could.

I created my own subclass of inline formset:

```
class MyInlineFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def _construct_form(self, i, **kwargs):
        initial = {}
        fname = '%s-%s-%s' % (self.prefix, i, 'important_field_name')
        initial['target_type'] = self.data[fname] if fname in self.data.keys() else 'km'
        kwargs.update({'initial':initial})
        form = super(MyInlineFormSet, self)._construct_form(i, **kwargs)
        return form
```

And then in the form class:

```
class MyNiftyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyAwesomeObject
        fields=('field_one', 'field_two', 'field_three')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ServiceTargetForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance:
            if self.instance.field_one == 'date':
                self.fields['field_one'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'datepicker'
        if self.initial:
            if self.initial['field_one'] == 'date':
                self.fields['field_one'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'datepicker'
```

and then in view:

```
MySuperCoolFormSet = inlineformset_factory(ImportantObject, MyAwesomeObject, extra = 1, form = MyNiftyForm, formset = MyInlineFormSet)
```

And it works.

Alan